# Is it safe to source system-wide environment variables in apache envvars?

Tags: php, linux, apache, environment-variables

I am trying to set an environment variable on Linux which should be available in shell as well as Apache.

I added the variable to `/etc/environment`, so the file looks something like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
MY_VAR="foo"
```

To have `MY_VAR` available in apache, this is what I added in `/etc/apache2/envvars`:

```
. /etc/environment
export MY_VAR=$MY_VAR
```

After doing a lot of research, this is the only way I was able to get the same environment variable work system-wide and in Apache without having to declare them twice.

Are there any security concerns with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem. I removed `MY_VAR` from `/etc/environment` and created a separate file `/etc/profile.d/apache.sh` which looks like this:

```
export MY_VAR="foo"
```

Then I sourced this file in `/etc/apache2/envvars` like so:

```
. /etc/profile.d/apache.sh
```

- Any variable set in `apache.sh` is available system-wide as well as in Apache
- Because `apache.sh` is a script, unlike `/etc/environment`, the variables do not have to be "export"ed again in `envvars`
- There is no security risk because no unwanted variables are passed magically to Apache
- Whatever variables you want to be available system-wide as well as Apache, you add it to `apache.sh` and if you want it only in Apache then you add it in `envvars`

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't need to use the keyword `export` when sourcing scripts.

Therefore the extra script (i.e. `my_apacheenv.sh`) should have this format:

```bash
VARIABLE_A="some hardcoded value"
VARIABLE_B="${DYNAMIC_ONE}"
VARIABLE_C="${APACHE_HOSTNAME}"
```

and be sure it is marked as executable (`chmod +x /path/to/my_apacheenv.sh`).

The file `/etc/apache2/envvars` should contain:

```bash
. /path/to/my_apacheenv.sh
```

Then you can define the value of `DYNAMIC_ONE` or `APACHE_HOSTNAME` in any usual way, either in the session or as environment variable.

For me, it works pretty well when used in combination of a docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  single-apache-php:
    build: ./../cicd/apache
    environment:
      APACHE_HOSTNAME: "my.dynamic.hostname.com"
```